# Passing array data from php to javascript using a loop

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a similar way to implement this kind of "algorithm" in the right way?

```
for(i=0;i<howManyCourses;i++){

            var stored = "<?php echo $buf[i] ?>";
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text=stored;
            e.add(option);

        }
```

So I want to pass the data from the $buf array into a javascript variable. I've tried many ways but it seems like I cannot find the solution. I'm new into php and I apologise for any obvious mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Above answer and JSON.  see: [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the same file or in another case **AJAX** will be the solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       const arr = <?php echo json_encode($buf); ?>;

       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
           //do something
       }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that JS' variable `buf` contain the same elements as PHP's `$buf`, you can do the following:

```
var buf = <?php echo json_encode($buf); ?>;
```

Just keep in mind that if PHP's `$buf` is not an indexed array, JS' `buf` will be an object instead of an array.